# How to place FrameView over Toolbar in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place FrameView over Toolbar as show in the image below -

[image]

You can see that the RecyclerView in the FrameView is overlapping Toolbar

But I'm getting this instead as show in the image below -

[image]

In the Android Studio preview its showing correctly which means frame layout is over the toolbar like this -

[image]

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_50">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/backButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/topicLogo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Quiz"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dim_19"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFragment.OnBaseFragListener {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView txtLabel;
    ImageButton backButton;
    ImageView topicLogo;
    int navHomeVisibility = 1;
    int navAboutVisibility = 1;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams labelParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        txtLabel = findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        topicLogo = findViewById(R.id.topicLogo);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        AddFrag(new ChooseTopicFragment(), 0, null);

        labelParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) txtLabel.getLayoutParams();
    }

    public void setTitleMargin() {
        labelParams.setMargins((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dim_10), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void unsetTitleMargin() {
        labelParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dim_1));
    }

    public void setFragTitle(String FragTitle) {
        txtLabel.setText(FragTitle);
    }

    public void setFragLogo(int FragLogo) {
        topicLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        topicLogo.setImageResource(FragLogo);
    }

    public void unsetFragLogo() {
        topicLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void unsetMenuItems(int navHomeFlag) {
        navHomeVisibility = navHomeFlag;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        backButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtLabel.setTextSize(20);
    }

    public void setMenuItems(int navHomeFlag) {
        navHomeVisibility = navHomeFlag;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtLabel.setTextSize(19);
    }


    public void unsetAbout(int navAboutFlag) {
        navAboutVisibility = navAboutFlag;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void setAbout(int navAboutFlag) {
        navAboutVisibility = navAboutFlag;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void unsetOnlyBackBtn() {
        backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void AddFrag(Fragment fragment, int flag, String fragName) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (flag == 0) {
            ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, fragName); //for adding ChooseTopic frag
        } else if (flag == 1) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragName);
            ft.addToBackStack(fragName);
        } else if (flag == 2) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragName); //skips adding Questions frag to backstack
        } else if (flag == 3) {
            ft.remove(fragment); //removes Result frag after pressing back
        }

        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem navHome = menu.findItem(R.id.navHome);
        if (navHomeVisibility == 0)
            navHome.setVisible(false);
        else
            navHome.setVisible(true);

        MenuItem navAbout = menu.findItem(R.id.navAbout);
        if (navAboutVisibility == 0)
            navAbout.setVisible(false);
        else
            navAbout.setVisible(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navHome) {
            finishAffinity();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navAbout) {
            AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            aboutDialog.setTitle("About");
            aboutDialog.setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.about_desc));

            aboutDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            aboutDialog.show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof BaseFragment) {
            BaseFragment baseFragment = (BaseFragment) fragment;
            baseFragment.setOnBaseFragListener(this);
        }

    }
}
```

**ChooseTopicFragment**

```
    public class ChooseTopicFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private ArrayList<TopicModal> arrTopicModal = new ArrayList<>();

    public ChooseTopicFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_topic, container, false);

        arrTopicModal.clear();

        callback.unsetMenuItems(0);
        callback.setAbout(1);
        callback.unsetFragLogo();
        callback.setFragTitle("Programming Quiz");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getDB(getActivity());

        if (!dbHelper.checkDB()) {
            dbHelper.createDB(getActivity());
        }
        dbHelper.openDB();

        ArrayList<Integer> arrBeg = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrInt = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrExp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            arrBeg.add(dbHelper.getCount("Beginner", i));
            arrInt.add(dbHelper.getCount("Intermediate", i));
            arrExp.add(dbHelper.getCount("Expert", i));
        }

        addTopics(1, R.drawable.ic_java, "Java", arrBeg.get(0), arrInt.get(0), arrExp.get(0), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        addTopics(2, R.drawable.ic_c, "C", arrBeg.get(1), arrInt.get(1), arrExp.get(1), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        addTopics(3, R.drawable.ic_cpp, "C++", arrBeg.get(2), arrInt.get(2), arrExp.get(2), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light));
        addTopics(4, R.drawable.ic_android, "Android", arrBeg.get(3), arrInt.get(3), arrExp.get(3), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));
        addTopics(5, R.drawable.ic_php, "PHP", arrBeg.get(4), arrInt.get(4), arrExp.get(4), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
        addTopics(6, R.drawable.ic_css, "CSS", arrBeg.get(5), arrInt.get(5), arrExp.get(5), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple));
        addTopics(7, R.drawable.ic_html, "HTML", arrBeg.get(6), arrInt.get(6), arrExp.get(6), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light));
        addTopics(8, R.drawable.ic_python, "Python", arrBeg.get(7), arrInt.get(7), arrExp.get(7), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        addTopics(9, R.drawable.ic_javascript, "Javascript", arrBeg.get(8), arrInt.get(8), arrExp.get(8), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        addTopics(10, R.drawable.ic_kotlin, "Kotlin", arrBeg.get(9), arrInt.get(9), arrExp.get(9), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark));

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        TopicAdapter adapter = new TopicAdapter(getActivity(), arrTopicModal);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void addTopics(int topicID, int image, String name, int beginner, int intermediate, int expert, int topicColor) {
        TopicModal topicModal = new TopicModal();

        topicModal.topicID = topicID;
        topicModal.image = image;
        topicModal.name = name;
        topicModal.beginner = beginner;
        topicModal.intermediate = intermediate;
        topicModal.expert = expert;
        topicModal.topicColor = topicColor;

        arrTopicModal.add(topicModal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant way but you could set the elevation on the different views to force which is on top. Also I believe within a frame layout  the order in which you add the layout in your xml plays an important role in what is causing your problems